# JQuery AJAX URL Rest path parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, url

I have a Rest service on /users/{userId}/orders/{orderId} (please note the path parameters) and I want to call it from JQuery.

I could do it simply concatenating the ids like so:

```
$.get(
    'users/' + 1234 + '/orders/' + 9876,
    function (data) {
        //do something with the response
    }
);
```

But this doesn't seem like a very correct way of doing it (although it does the job).

Is there a better way of passing these path parameters on the URL of a JQuery AJAX call?

*** just to clarify, my concern is more with the concatenation of the string. I wonder if there's a better way to construct the url without concatenating strings. Perhaps string formatting would be better?**

Comment: I think you should change your Rest service using path variables

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "change your Rest service using path variables"?

Comment: I mean you should use arguments in url like yourservice?userid=xxx&orders=yyy

Comment: Yeah but that wouldn't be very Restful-ly and sometimes you need to call an existing service and don't have control over the use of path or query params.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is the neatest way to proceed here:

```
$.get(
    `users/${userId}/orders/${orderId}`,
    function (data) {
        //do something with the response
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to make this request :

```
function makeOrderRequest(userId, orderId, sucessCallback) {
    $.get('users/' + userId + '/orders/' + orderId, successCallback);
}
```

And then call it when you need :

```
makeOrderRequest(1234, 8796, function(data){
     //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks, my concern is more to do with the string concatenation. You are still concatenating strings in the url in your example. I wonder if there's a better way to do it which doesn't involve that.

Comment: Ok. I think concatenation is good here, but you can use an object like {order:1234,user:8765} then generate the URL with a loop to avoid manual concatenation.